# Dplyr add_row adding whole dataframe to grouped data instead of a single row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this: `

```r
> head(df)
   Sample Site Site.Type Substrate.Type   Date Emerged
1 A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/2/22      NA
2 A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/3/22      NA
3 A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/4/22      NA
4 A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/5/22       0
5 A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/6/22       0
6 A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/7/22       0
```

```r
> tail(df)
     Sample Site Site.Type Substrate.Type    Date Emerged
27 C 3 6/12   B      Type3          TypeR 6/12/22      NA
28 C 3 6/12   B      Type3          TypeR 6/13/22       0
29 C 3 6/12   B      Type3          TypeR 6/14/22       0
30 C 3 6/12   B      Type3          TypeR 6/15/22       1
31 C 3 6/12   B      Type3          TypeR 6/16/22       1
32 C 3 6/12   B      Type3          TypeR 6/17/22       0
```

There are different samples, each with a count for the number of organisms emerging from the sample on given date. I would like to add rows with more recent dates for each sample - foe example, for sample "A 1 6/5", I want to add a row that contains the same exact info for the first 4 columns, but with date "6/18/2022" and the count for that day. Since most of the counts are zeros, I was trying to automate it using dplyr and adding the row to each group and a 0 for emergence. here is my code so far:

```r
df <- df %>%
      group_split(Sample) %>%
      map_dfr(~ add_row(.x,Sample = .$Sample, Site = .$Site,
                        Site.Type = .$Site.Type, 
                        Substrate.Type = .$Substrate.Type,
                        Date = c("6/18/22"),Emerged= 0))
```

I don't know why, but this doubles the length of the dataframe, with the date column always populated with "6/18/2022" for the added rows. I want it to just add one row with the specified date. Actually, bonus points if you can help me figure out how to add multiple rows with the continuing dates (6/19,6/20 etc) but I can make do with one row. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sample is a variable name, group_split groups by and then splits on that group in one step. @CarBarb, can you post the `dput` of the dataframe instead, so we can see multiple groups? It is hard to read in as some of your variables have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  split(~Sample) %>% 
  # group_split(Sample) %>%
  map_df(~ .x %>% 
           add_row(Sample=.$Sample[1],
                   Site = .$Site[1],
                   Site.Type = .$Site.Type[1],
                   Substrate.Type = .$Substrate.Type[1], 
                   Date = "6/18/22",
                   Emerged =0))
```

```
        Sample Site Site.Type Substrate.Type    Date Emerged
1      A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA  6/2/22      NA
2      A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA  6/3/22      NA
3      A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA  6/4/22      NA
4      A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA  6/5/22       0
5      A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA  6/6/22       0
6      A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA  6/7/22       0
...7   A 1 6/5    A     Type1          TypeA 6/18/22       0
27    C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/12/22      NA
28    C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/13/22       0
29    C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/14/22       0
30    C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/15/22       1
31    C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/16/22       1
32    C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/17/22       0
...14 C 3 6/12    B     Type3          TypeR 6/18/22       0
```